# Any way to batch updates/subscribe to two atoms in Nanostores?

Tags: javascript, astrojs, nanostores

I'm exploring Nanostores as an alternative to Solid JS and I'm just wondering whether there is something equivalent to Solid's `batch` function, i.e.:

```
const x = atom(0);
const y = atom(0);

function handleMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
  // Some way to batch updates here?
  x.set(event.offsetX);
  y.set(event.offsetY);
}

document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);

// Such that there's only one update when *both* x and y change?
const xy = atom([0, 0]);
x.subscribe((v) => xy.set([v, xy.get()[1]]));
y.subscribe((v) => xy.set([xy.get()[0], v]));

xy.subscribe(console.log);
```